# How can I communicate with a printer via USB using java in windows platform

Tags: java, printing

How can I communicate with a printer via USB using java in windows platform? I don't want to use JNI. I want to use jsr80 or libusb-win32 if any experienced have work with that please share his/her knowledge with some code. I think in libusb-win32 java wrapper must install some driver, correct?  I don't want to use any driver. I want to designing my application like plug and play type device by which I can send file easily. I don't want to buy any software.

Is there any other way to communicate with printer?

Comment: After searching a long time, i find a solution that if i write a driver for that using c and then call it from java it can be possible.I get help from http://blog.peter.skarpetis.com/archives/2005/04/07/getting-a-handle-on-usbprintsys/ this site but still now i have no idea upon wsdk and wddk if anyone have some idea please share.

How can i add it with java code?

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with most usb devices a driver is required. In most cases though the driver should already be installed on the target pc unless this is a remote printing application. Also most printer drivers are free so you shouldn't need to buy anything.

Comment: but when a pendrive is attached with cpu is there any driver is needed to send file?????I think no except inbox driver which is operating system  have.....I want to this as same manner witout any pendriver driver we can send file....so why not i can send file to printer.....

Comment: Pen drives are not the same as printers. Printers have there own processors which communicate with the software on the computer. Pen drives are essentially sd cards or hard drives and can be directly managed by the os.

Comment: I want to bypass the application driver.I want to use windows driver and print file using it.usbprint.sys file in windows os manage the printing if i access this file then it is possible,but it is a system file so it is not possible to  access but we can send file to this usbprint.sys and then it will manage this sended file.we achieve it by using windows driver programming.Do you have any idea upon that? Is it possible using java?